# Ext.application: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having some issues with my extjs 5 application. I am using Sencha Architect and im running the application on FreeBSD.

The error I am getting is Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for 'Ext.application'

Here is my code

```
// @require @packageOverrides
Ext.Loader.setConfig({

});


Ext.application({
models: [
    'BassSearch',
    'BassSearchResult',
    'Menu',
    'Customer',
    'Subscription',
    'NetInfo',
    'Products',
    'AddressSearch',
    'AddressAll',
    'Interface',
    'Phone'
],
stores: [
    'SearchStore',
    'CustomerStore',
    'NetinfoStore',
    'InterfaceStore',
    'PhoneStore',
    'BassMenuStore',
    'JsonSubscriptions'
],
views: [
    'fSearch',
    'searchResult',
    'SearchPanel',
    'ApplicationPanel',
    'MenuPanel',
    'MainBass',
    'CustomerInfoView'
],
controllers: [
    'searchController',
    'MenuSubController',
    'CustomerInfoController'
],
name: 'MyApp',

launch: function() {
    Ext.create('MyApp.view.MainBass');
    //load
    var myCookieVal = document.cookie.indexOf('basssessionid');
    if (myCookieVal) {
        window.location.href="index.html";
    } else {
        var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var request = 'api/checkSession';
        xhReq.open("GET", request, false);
        xhReq.send(null);
        var json = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
        if (!json.success) {
            window.location.href="index.html";
        }
    }
    Ext.define('BASSSharedData', {cid: 0});

    MyApp.globals = {
        currentcid: 0,
        userid: 0,
        callback: "",
        subscriptionid: 0,
        currentView: null
    };


}
```

});

Any help appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error usually means that you're calling a function of an object which is not yet initialised (closest resemblance is NullPointerException in JAVA). If xhReq.send(null); is asynchronous or it fails, xhreq.responseText should be null/undefined when you call it in the next statement.

Go through this tutorial to learn about how to use 'XMLHTTPRequest'. If xhReq.responseText isn't the cause, try debugging the code using Chrome or Firefox's Firebug or else put 'alert()' at different places to see where is the source of the cause.

Comment: Hello Varun,
Thanks for your reply.

I am developing this on a test server, which uses the same backend as the our production, and on the production server it works fine.

Comment: You can also try the 'alert()' thing or 'console.log()' then. I too faced discrepancies in the behaviour of client with test/production server. But mine was supposed to be packaged as a mobile app and the issue had something to do with cross-domain requests.